# Models design versus DTOs

Tags: mvvm, uwp

I'm a newbie developing an UWP-MVVM app, so I have a Db that contains a main table Purchases that uses four depending tables to record Items PurchaseItems->Inventory->SubProduct->Product. So my question is that when desing these tables Models, should I implement the same kind of nesting in the models or the right thing would be to create a single model that holds the necessary bits of the PurchaseItems table and sub tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is that when desing these tables Models, should I implement the same kind of nesting in the models or the right thing would be to create a single model that holds the necessary bits of the PurchaseItems table and sub tables?

It should be based on your design, you could implement the same kind of nesting in the models, this benefit is to help you access all depending tables easily, but the data structure looks redundant.

And you could also create a single model that holds the necessary bits of the PurchaseItems table and sub tables, it makes the data structure simpler, but you may not be able to access all the data tables deirctly.

So, you need to make the model base on your design, if you want the model easy to use, please select the first way, and if you want to the make a simple structure, please select second way.